# Mysql SUBTIME(time(end), time(start)) giving negative value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to calculate duration from start_time to end_time therefore I use `SUBTIME(TIME(end_time), TIME(start_time)) as duration` query which works well where both start_time and end_time are within same day.

Here is code to create MRE:

```
create table mre(
  id int,
  start_time datetime,
  end_time datetime,
  desired VARCHAR(40)
);

insert into mre (id, start_time, end_time, desired)
values 
  (1, "2019-10-10 23:59:59", "2019-10-11 00:01:01", "no"),
  (2, "2019-10-10 22:11:11", "2019-10-10 23:11:11", "yes"),
  (3, "2019-10-10 11:00:59", "2019-10-10 13:43:01", "yes"),
  (4, "2019-10-10 23:57:59", "2019-10-11 00:00:01", "no");
```

so now when I run

```
select 
  *,
  subtime(time(end_time), time(start_time)) as duration
from mre;
```

It outputs

```
   id        start_time           end_time    desired   duration
    1   2019-10-10 23:59:59 2019-10-11 00:01:01 no      -23:58:58
    2   2019-10-10 22:11:11 2019-10-10 23:11:11 yes     01:00:00
    3   2019-10-10 11:00:59 2019-10-10 13:43:01 yes     02:42:02
    4   2019-10-10 23:57:59 2019-10-11 00:00:01 no      -23:57:58
```

First line start from 2019-10-10 but ends at 2019-10-11. If you look at the time the difference between the two should be 00:01:02 which is what I want.

but instead it gives me  `00:01:01 - 23:59:59 = -23:58:58.`

switching places of end_time and start_time doesn't make sense (I've tried it just in case).

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've just figured out it is because inside subtime function I wrap end_time and start_time with TIME() therefore it ignores dates.

So I've tried doing it w/o TIME() which give null values for duration column.

Comment: what about TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,from, to)?

Comment: Yep, it seems like you're in the verge of figuring this out for yourself

Comment: @Strawberry Yep, all the time I figure it out after posting SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized the name SUBTIME have "TIME" in it which probably suggest that it only considers time therefore it required me to wrap time inside Time() and gave null value when I've tried to insert datetime object.

Thanks to https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php
I've figured out that when you want to consider date as well when calculating for duration you need to use TIMEDIFF() function.

I didn't find SO question regarding this matter (maybe too simple) so I've decided to keep it open.

Comment: you wouldn't bother what? wouldn't bother keeping it open?

Comment: hm... I couldn't find question on SO but there are lots of resources regarding this matter so therefore close it?

Comment: I'll keep it open since I tend to search in SO whenever problem arise but if anyone finds duplicate question regarding this matter I am willing to close it. @Strawberry Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  *,
  TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time) as duration
from mre;
```

or

```
select 
  *,
  SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)) as duration
from mre;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=32f167eefcdbe442d0cdc12a75e9df8f)

If `duration` exceeds 838:59:59 (35 days) then it will be truncated to this value (TIME datatype limitation).